# Mysql sum of fields not working when either field is NULL

Tags: php, mysql, select, sum, ifnull

Hi i have this code in php to update a balance field in $table5. Now my problem is that when one of the two fields i.e. `add` or `sub` is NULL then this does not return balance.

```
    $fetch_balance = mysql_query("SELECT (SUM (IFNULL(`add`,0))-(SUM (IFNULL(`sub`,0)))          AS `bal` FROM `".$table5."` ");
```

Please help.

Comment: Your code snippet has unbalanced parentheses in the query, so the lack of results is probably due to an error rather than `IFNULL`, which will definitely do what you're expecting it to do. You don't need all those parentheses, so just try `"SELECT SUM(IFNULL(add, 0)) - SUM(IFNULL(sub, 0)) FROM $table5"` for your query string assignment.

Comment: @EdGibbs, good catch on the imbalanced parentheses. Looks like another case of a developer failing to check for mysql_query() returning `false`.

Comment: There's also the space between `SUM` and the first `(`, which doesn't work as expected in all MySQL servers.

Comment: thank you all for your insights and efforts. @nanashi dri's answer works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your query, and it worked just fine, after some slight tweak: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6220/4

The final query should look like this: 
`SELECT (SUM(IFNULL(add,0)))-(SUM(IFNULL(sub,0)))
AS bal FROM ".$table5."`

You forgot to add a `)`, and also, you had spaces after SUM(). SUM is a function, and should therefore not have any spaces before the `()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query simplified to be syntactically correct:

```
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(`add`, 0) - SUM(IFNULL(`sub`, 0) AS `bal`
FROM `".$table5."`;
```

Assuming the table has rows, then this will return a single, non-NULL value for `bal`.  If the table has no rows, then it will return `NULL`.

You probably intend this logic:

```
select coalesce(sum(`add`), 0) - coalesce(sum(`sub`), 0) as bal
from . . .;
```

This does the replacement only if the entire `sum()` is `NULL`.  The `sum()` aggregation function treats `NULL` values as `0`.

Note:  I replaced the `ifnull()` function with the ANSI standard equivalent `coalesce()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table foo (bar1 integer, bar2 integer);

insert into foo (bar1, bar2) values (null, 1);
insert into foo (bar1, bar2) values (1, null);

select sum(coalesce(bar1, 0) + coalesce(bar2, 0)) from foo;
>2

select sum(bar1 + bar2) from foo;
>null
```

**EDIT** hint: try something like this:

```
SELECT SUM ( IFNULL(`add`,0) - IFNULL(`sub`,0) )
```